# VB.NET Saving Genereted QR Code A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

Tags: vb.net

So here whenever i try to saved image this error show up "'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'"

Here is the code in my button 1

`SaveImageCopy(TextBox1.Text, PictureBox1.Image)`

Here is the code of Saving The Location of QR Code

```
    Dim paths As String = "C:\LIST OF QR CODE" & filename & ".jpg"
    Dim dest As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dest)
    gfx.DrawImageUnscaled(image, Point.Empty)
    gfx.Dispose()
    dest.Save(paths, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    dest.Dispose()
```

So what did i do wrong here? Should i use stream writer?

Comment: @Nkosi i got another error when i used your code. This error Show up 
"A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Answer (score 0):

I replace the
Dim paths As String = "C:\LIST OF QR CODE" & filename & ".jpg"

with

Dim paths As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Container", IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "jpg"))